# Java: Cannot find symbol but typing is correct

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

I made a class `Operator` and a method called `compare`. However, when call this method in my program, I always got error message

`InfixToPostfix.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(compare(op,op1));
                                   ^
  symbol:   method compare(Operator,Operator)
  location: class InfixToPostfix`

I think I did not make any spell mistakes.

```
public class Operator extends Token {

    protected String val; //Modified by Qinjianhong Yang, 11/18/16

    public boolean isOperator() { return true; }
    public boolean isOperand() { return false; }

            // helper method, returns (assigns) precedence for operators
    protected int getPrec()
    {
            //modified by Qinjianhong Yang, 11/17/2016
            if(this.val.equals("+") || this.val.equals("-")){
                    return 1;
            }
            else return 2;

    }

            // handy for comparing 2 operators
    public static int compare( Operator a, Operator b )
    {
            if( a.getPrec() == b.getPrec() )
                    return 0;
            else if( a.getPrec() < b.getPrec() )
                    return -1;
            else
                    return 1;
    }

    public String getVal() { return this.val; }

    public Operator( String v ) { this.val = v; }

}
```

I call this function like this:

```
 Operator op = new Operator("+");
 Operator op1 = new Operator("*");
 System.out.println(compare(op,op1));
```

Comment: Note that the error message says it's look in class `InfixToPostfix`, but your `compare` method is in class `Operator`. Do this instead: `System.out.println(Operator.compare(op,op1));`

Comment: Unless you `import` the method, you have to say `Operator.compare(op,op1)`.

Answer (score 2):

> I call this function like this:
>
> ```
> Operator op = new Operator("+");
> Operator op1 = new Operator("*");
> System.out.println(compare(op,op1));
> ```

The error message tells us that code is in the class `InfixToPostfix`, but using `compare` without any qualifier would only work

- for code inside the `Operator` class, or
- if you used a static import:

  ```
    import static Operator.compare;
  ```

Otherwise, you have to tell the compiler where `compare` comes from:

```
System.out.println(Operator.compare(op,op1));
// ----------------^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Side note: The name "`compare`" suggests you're comparing the `Operator` as a whole, but your `compare` only compares the operator's *precedence*, ignoring its `val`. So for instance, `Operator.compare(new Operator("*"), new Operator("/"))` would return `0`, which is surprising. If it's only going to compare precedence, I would suggest calling it `comparePrecedence` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use: `System.out.println(Operator.compare(op,op1));`. You must add the classname if you call the static function outside of it

Answer (score 0):

`compare(op,op1)` method is `static`, so you need to add the class name `Operator` to invoke it as shown below:

```
System.out.println(Operator.compare(op,op1));
```